# ALSA error on raspberry pi4 when running speech recognition program

Tags: python, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi4

I am currently working on a speech recognition program on my raspberry pi4. I have already installed the speechRecognition, pyaudio and pyspeech libraries. I have also checked my audio device id and all of the ids were correct.

This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listening = True

while listening:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        recognizer.energy_threshold = 1568
        recognizer.dynamic_energy_threshold = True

        try:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
            response = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print(response)

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sorry....")
```

This is the error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
Segmentation fault
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an error with `ALSA`, not with the `speech_recognition` package. What is happening here is that `ALSA` cannot find your soundcard. Please try a different configuration using `alsamixer`.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer, but can you please elaborate more on, ' try a different configuration using alsamixer'. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.bristolwatch.com/debian/alsamixer.htm

Comment: thank you for the response but when I am running the sudo chmod +x alsamixer.sh command, it is not giving any output....

Comment: what is the output of `which alsamixer`?